# Get value of environment variable from parameter

Tags: powershell

How can I get the value of an environment variable named in a function parameter?
E.g.,

```
function echo-env($var) {echo "value of $var is $env:$var"}
```

Returns PowerShell error:

> Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.

EDIT: The question that this was marked a duplicate of indeed answered my question, giving me this working result:

```
function echo-env($var) {echo "set $var to $((Get-Item env:$var).Value)"}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer from the pointed-to question seemed simplest to me, which is what I used: `function echo-env($var) {echo "set $var to $((Get-Item env:$var).Value)"}`

Answer (score 1):

Query the `env:` environment provider PSDrive instead:

```
function echo-env {
  param([string]$var)

  if($ev = Get-Item env:\$var){
    "value of $var is $($ev.Value)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use .NET:

```
function echo-env($var) {
    "value of '$var' is: $([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($var))"
}
```